ubuntu 22.04 won't boot
I installed Ubuntu 22.04 at the end of 2022. Until yesterday October 10, 2024, the system was working normally, but yesterday I got this text on the display.
When I typed 'help', this text appeared on the display.



This question is similar to: fsck error on boot: /dev/sda6: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
